# Permanently change system color temperature

Tags: color-management, redshift, gnome-color-manager

I want to change my system screen color settings to red color temperature of 3000k. I am using ubuntu 16.04LTS, I have also tried with Flux and redshift, It doesn't help me.

Flux - doesn't have permanent color shift for 24/7

Answer (score 4):

Hacky way, but that's all I can come up with it.

Install redshift-gtk

```
sudo apt install redshift-gtk
```

Create `.config/redshift.conf` file in your home directory with the following content. Add redshift-gtk to the startup.

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=3000
temp-night=3000
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=11.11
lon=22.22
```